# sequlize model cannot be fetched

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using [this scotch tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize) to create a basic node application using the sequelize js for ORM, here is my models/index.js:

and I am unable to use my user model with the user controller:

my model :

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define('user', {
    name: {
      type : DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull : false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {});
  user.associate = function(models) {
    user.hasMany(models.wish, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'wishes'
    });
  };
  return user;
};
```

and here is my controller:

```
    const user = require('../models').user;


module.exports = {
        create(req, res){
                return user.create({
                        name: req.body.name,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: req.body.password }).then( 
                                todo => res.status(201).send(user)
                         ).catch( 
                                 error => res.status(400).send(error)
                        );
        }
}
```

but for some reason a big error comes on my screen and crashes the application, what I diagnosed from that error is that my controller is not able to find the 'user' model AND and I tried to link a bunch of things like giving the path to user directly but it did not work.

[here](https://pastebin.com/GzX3d8rM) is the error if you need (I am a newbee so could be totaly wrong about this)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this line :

```
const user = require('../models').user;
```

to

```
const user = require('../models');
```